# yarn init -2 doesn't generate yarnrc.yml file

Tags: node.js

I've recently tried to initialize Yarn on a web project of mine. I've followed the official installation guide, navigating to the correct directory and running `yarn init -2`. Whilst it seems to have worked, I cannot find the `yarnrc.yml` file that changes the settings. I've attached an image to show the working directory, and how `yarnrc.yml` isn't there. How can I generate a `yarnrc.yml` file?

[working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVPy6.png)

Comment: Note [tag:yarnpkg] is for Yarn v1/"classic", which doesn't support zero installs.